# Oracle Forms Comment Line Shortcut

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Is there any shortcut for to make all chosen lines comment lines in Oracle Forms 10g?

I've been searching some, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcut? Such as manually typing `--` at the beginning of the line? There's nothing *shorter* than that (if you meant something like `Ctrl + B` or similar), as far as I can tell.

Comment: I mean I want to choose lines and make all chosen lines comment line with shortcut (like Ctrl + B).

Comment: As I've said, there's nothing like that in any Oracle Forms version I know (up to 10g).

Comment: Ok. This is 10g

Answer (score 0):

You could use block comments.  Put `/*` at the beginning of the section of code you want commented, and `*/` at the end.

Comment: I've been working in Forms for over 20 years, and as far I know, there's no shortcuts to comment out a section of code.  This is the shortest method you will find.